# How to block comment or tags in document comment using Javadoc

Tags: java, html, image, annotations, javadoc

How to block img tag or any line in Java doc. When I place the cursor on class it is showing multiple times. For feature reference I am using both img tags in doc comment(document comment). Can anybody tell me how to show only one img tag by blocking `<img src="../../../../resources/images/java-basic-ASCII Table.png" />` line.

```
package com.java.escapesequence;

/**
 * 
 * @author udaykiranp
 * 
 * </br>
 *  <img src="../../../../resources/images/java-basic-ASCII Table.png" />
 * 
 *  <img src="{@docRoot}/../resources/images/java-basic-ASCII Table.png" />
 */
public class CharSequence {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println((char) 33);
        System.out.println((char)0x2B);//hexa decimal start with 0x
        System.out.println((char)056);//octa decimal start with 0
    }
}
```

**Image when placing cursor on class:**

[image: Img tag blocking in Java doc]

Comment: I don't think it's possible. But why on earth do you have two `img` tags?

Comment: Remove the line?

Comment: Also completely unrelated: not great to have a class named `CharSequence`.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Just for reference I mentioned two img tags.

Comment: Put it as a see-also link. Don't force every reader of the Javadoc to be confronted with an image. It's as bad there as it is here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want to use two tags and need to block other tag / comment for feature reference in javadoc we need to use **See Also** using @see link.

```
package com.java.escapesequence;

/**
 * 
 * @author udaykiranp
 * 
 * </br>
 *
 *  <img src="{@docRoot}/../resources/images/java-basic-ASCII Table.png" />
 *  @see <a href="../../../../resources/images/java-basic-ASCII Table.png">java-basic-ASCII Table.png</a>
 */
public class CharSequence {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println((char) 33);
        System.out.println((char)0x2B);//hexa decimal start with 0x
        System.out.println((char)056);//octa decimal start with 0
    }
}
```

**Java Doc:**
[image: java-basic-ASCII Table.png]